# Own command for \mintinline cannot handle hash character

Tags: minted

I'm using the following command to create my own version of `\mintinline`:

```
\newcommand{\inline}[1]{{\mintinline[fontsize=\normalsize]{text}{#1}}}
```

This works except when I'm using the hash character. For instance:

```
\inline{Class#method()}
```

Which gets rendered with two hashes (i.e. `Class##method()`). When I replace my own command with `\mintinline[fontsize=\normalsize]{text}{…}`, everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong in my `\newcommand` definition?

Comment: as with most "verbatim" commands, you cannot include in another command using standard definition  forms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just avoid absorbing the text beforehand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\inline}{\mintinline[fontsize=\normalsize]{text}}

\begin{document}

Text \inline{Class#method()} text

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the preferred method is with `\newmintinline`, so the defined command can take options in the standard way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newmintinline[inline]{text}{fontsize=\normalsize}

\begin{document}

Text \inline{Class#method()} text

Text \inline[fontsize=\small]{Class#method()} text

\end{document}
```

[image]