# package minted displays two # instead of one

Tags: minted

I am using package `minted` within `beamer` in order to display LaTeX source code.

Actually, I am having this code to display:

```
\newcommand{\vektor}[1]{\vec{#1}}
```

so i coded something like this within an `\uncover` instruction:

```
\mint{latex}|\newcommand{\vektor}[1]{\vec{#1}}|
```

and tried different options like `\mint[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true]{l...` but nothing helped so far.  The problem is, that the `#` will be presented twice in the output :-(

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \uncover<1->{\mint{latex}|\newcommand{\vektor}[1]{\vec{#1}}|}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem occurs from using the `\uncover`, but I would love to use that feature :-(

This is the unpleasant result:

[image: One hash to much]

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394072/own-command-for-mintinline-cannot-handle-hash-character helps.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you.  I was not able to see, how I could adapt this to my situation :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put verbatim material in an argument. Use the uncoverenv instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{uncoverenv}<1->\mint{latex}|\newcommand{\vektor}[1]{\vec{#1}}|\end{uncoverenv}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Ulrike Fischer, thank you so much.  It worked!