# newcommand to apply mintinline for C++ breaks on include statements

Tags: macros, minted, code, protected-macro

Staying away from LaTeX for barely more than 2 years has devastating effects.

I think once I knew how to protect this stuff, but I have no idea now.

I defined the `newcommand` below to be faster in writing C++ code inline (and I have a similar macro for other languages). However, it looks like it doesn't really like the `#` of include statements:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\cpp}[1]{\mintinline{c++}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\mintinline{c++}{#include <iostream>} % ok
\\
\cpp{#include <iostream>} % renders as `##include <iostream>`

\end{document}
```

Comment: mintinline like all verb commands can not be used in the argument or definition of another command. Here it makes `#` safe but that can not work as it has already been read by `\cpp` as a special character before minted sees it

Comment: Can't test because I don't have a Python installation on my PC at the moment, but often with "verbatim" issues like this the "magic trick" is to avoid making the argument explicit in the `\newcommand`: `\newcommand{\cpp}{\mintinline{c++}}` might work. (Of course these kind of tricks making the "verbatim" argument explicit do not always work.)

Comment: @moewe yes that would work

Comment: @moewe, it works, thanks. I think you can answer, or most probably mark this question as a duplicate of another one.

Comment: You may also be interested in `\newmintinline` to define your own `\mintinline`-like command directly.

Comment: As far as duplicates are concerned I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394072/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444122/35864. I think the first is a perfect match for your question. WDYT?

Comment: Yeah, I've marked the question as dup myself.